# Check if element exists within root/child

Tags: java, android, xml, libgdx

I have a XML file with multiple of the same childs. Each holding different types of elements. I need to parse this and instead of creating an extra element to direct the parsing to the types of elements the child holds I'd like to know if it is possible to detect if an element exists or not within a child.

```
if (action.get("variableElement") != null) System.out.println(action.get("variableElement"));
// Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Element action doesn't have attribute or child: variableElement
```

So is there a way i could check if this child exist or not? I am using the `LibGDX` `XmlReader` library for parsing my XML.

Comment: I doubt wou'll get that `Exception` using `XmlPullParser` from Android: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. How do you parse your XML?

Comment: @shkschneider using th libgdx XmlReader library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, I can see that `get(key, default_value)` can throw an Exception.
Since you do not provide a default value, it gets thrown if it does not exists, as the documentation specifies.

Try to give a default value to your `get()`, like `null` or an empty string, and check that value afterwards, without having an Exception.